Romer-Romer shocks in a monetary VAR
I'm trying to better understand implementing Romer-&-Romer monetary shocks in a monetary (S)VAR.
If I start with a standard VAR of prices, output and the Federal funds rate, I can do a Cholesky ordering and assess the impulse responses to a temporary FFR innovation. All fine. But when you include the exogenous R&R shocks, is it
(a) enough to simply re-estimate the VAR with the R&R shocks as an exogenous variable, and repeat the exercise?
(b) or would you re-estimate the VAR and then shock instead the R&R exogenous variable?
Thanks.
